# Восстановление сессии Java

Tags: java, servlet

Добрый день! 
У меня есть сервлет и клиент http. Я ставлю таймаут сессии.Клиент делает первый запрос , таймаут проходит и встает вопрос. Можно ли проверить факт смерти в самом сервлете(как это сделать?) , а потом восстановить эту сессию. В интернете пишут про таинственный мэнэджер сессий, который это умеет, но я ничего не выяснил об этом. 
PS хотелось бы решение без введения БД сессий и их пар "ключ-значение".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос, как и многие другие, можно найти в [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpRequest.html). Если вызывать getSession без параметров, то новая сессия создается автоматически. Если вызывать getSession(<boolean>) с параметром false, то если сессия истекла вернется null.

Comment: да, я не заметил getSession(false). А как быть с восстановлением?

Comment: Не знаю, по идее данные истекшей сессии удаляются контейнером. Если нужно что-то хранить, то надо как-то идентифицировать каждого клиента, и хранить связанные с ним данные отдельно.